# Emitting message to multiple namespaces concurrently

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I just recently started working with `socket.io` and seem to be running into an issue. I have implemented multiple namespaces where I can emit data coming into the server. However, I have realized that I can only emit data to a single namespace at a time and only when that completes does data to the second namespace begin emitting. Is there someway I can have this work concurrently?

If anyone has any idea, how I would go about tackling this issue, I would greatly appreciate any advice and links to resources.